# iPhone UIImage number recognition

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode, sdk

I have a small UIImage (jpg) with a single typed number. I want to be able to read the number with some kind of pattern recognition. I'm really not sure where to start, so any help would be appreciated.

my initial idea was to compare this image with other images. For instance compare the image with that of a 1,2,3, etc until a match was found. That just seems slow and cumbersome and wondered if there was a better way to do it?

Thanks

Update - I'm trying to convert sudoku puzzles from newspaper print to interactive puzzles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are right, it will be slow and cumbersome. But on the plus side you don't have to write it yourself

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/

Still not exactly easy tho, and i'm not sure about licensing, so… you don't mention why you need to do this (sounds a little odd).

Maybe you can avoid it? If you know the images are numerical digits 0-9, is there another way to track which one a particalur images is, apart from the way it's pixels are arranged?

Sorry if that sounds like i'm missing the point… Maybe you could fill in a few more details?

Comment: Ahhhhh.... Would someone really post to SO about how to bypass a  CAPTCHA? Jeez.. kids nowadays!

Comment: Lol no I'm not trying to bypass captcha I'm trying to convert sudoku images from a newspaper into interactive sudoku puzzles!!!

Comment: you should check out this http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/ 
i think it uses openCV to recognise screenshots of gui components so you can script them, eg so you take a screenshot of the button you want it to press at 4pm and you include it in a little script, and at 4 pm it will search the screen to find and recognise that button - allowing for fuzziness - and then press it.

Answer (score 0):

I read this really good write-up about this exact problem here: http://sudokugrab.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-does-it-all-work.html

It doesn't have any code samples, but explains the concepts, and might be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The following tutorial may be right down your alley:
http://blog.damiles.com/2008/11/basic-ocr-in-opencv/
It is a simple tutorial on doing number recognition and comes with the source code also.

Additionally, you may want to do a search on OCR SDK (Optical Character Recognition Software Development Kit). You will surely find a stack of them. Commercial ones a pricey though.

I would go for a "role your own" approach along the line of the OpenCV tutorial, especially since you are only interested in numbers.

All of the best ':-)